# Opening an activity in Android without having to Reload it from scratch

Tags: android, screen, android-intent

I would like to know If there is a way wherein we can come back to a previously loaded activity without having to reload its contents from scratch . Since my application downloads content from a web site , I don't want it to download the contents each time i load the activity but only when explicitly mentioned .

Comment: Simply dont finish the activity when moving away from it

Comment: Look at my answer, Hope you will get what you needed.

Comment: That doesn't help because any way when i come back ... it reloads the activity even if i haven't finished() it .

Comment: Look at my edited answer. Hope now you will understand it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `StartActivityForResult()` and **don't finish()** the activity, You will land to that activity on method `onActivityResult().`

EDIT:

```
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_OK);
```

and

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
       // When you are back from second Activity you are land here ..
       // do what ever you want to, without re Creating the this Activity 
    }
}
```

Comment: Will i have to explicitly define the latter method ?

Comment: yes its your activity's method. You have to just implement it. like onCreate() or other methods.

Comment: Ok my fetching of data and display of contents is done in the onCreate() method . Now when i come back , it enters this onActivityResult() method ... so will the contents displayed previously after fetching the data still be visible ? I am new to android so please bare with me if this seems very trivial .

Comment: Yes, as per Activity not destroyed your activity's previous state remain as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Activity done not finish untill we finish it or DVM finish it. you can use back functionality of android like

```
Activity.this.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));
```

On click of user defined back button . This code will act same as back functionality of device back button.

And yes don not start activity or finish activity or set flag while moving between activities , that can change your result a lot